# How can I write the ArrayList count to LogCat?

Tags: java, android, string, casting, android-logcat

In testing a query that returns N records, I want to log the count of records returned, but this attempt to do so:

```
Button fetchVendorsByCoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fetchVendorsByCoBtn);
fetchVendorsByCoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SQLiteHandlerVendors sqliteHandler = new SQLiteHandlerVendors(MainActivity.this, null, null, 1);
        ArrayList<Vendor> vens = sqliteHandler.findVendorsByCompanyName("[blank]");
        Log.i("Number of blankety-blank Vendors found", ((String) vens.size()));
    }
});
```

...fails with, "*error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String*"

...as does this:

```
Log.i("Number of matching Vendors found", ((String) vens.size()));
```

It would seem an int val would automatically get converted to String, and if not, at least a cast would work; but neither do.

How can I legally log this value?

Comment: a simple way to cast to string add empty string try vens.size() + ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
String.valueOf( vens.size());
```

or

```
Integer.toString( vens.size());
```

You can't assign an int to String.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative minimalistic way:

```
vens.size() + ""
```

so your log would look like this:

```
Log.i("Number of matching Vendors found", vens.size()+"");
```

Answer (score -2):

have you tried toString()

```
vens.size().toString()
```

Alternatively try doing this:

```
String.format("%d",vens.size());
```

Comment: int doesn't have toString() method.

Comment: @Braj is right. primitive type int does not have methods.